# Key Command for "Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local" on Mac

Tags: evaluation

I have an accidental run away loop in some code and Wolfram Desktop 13 is frozen. Usually when this happens I simply execute "Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local". This time however its so frozen I can't even do that. So my question is what is the key command for this? I thought it was Alt + . but that's not doing anything. Can I quit the kernel from the terminal somehow? I don't want to force quit and loose the code. Again I am on a Mac not Windows, running Wolfram Desktop 13.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a frequent occurrence for me.  If it is the kernel and not the front-end that is causing the hang, then *sometimes* this works: 1) on the mac, open the "Activity Monitor" app.  2) Look for the WolframKernel which is utilizing most of the CPU, select that and "Force Quit".  This keeps the FrontEnd alive but it will be equivalent to restarting the kernel--you will lose any computations you have done.  (You can do the same thing with the command "top" in a Terminal on the mac).  If this is useful, I'll post as an answer.